# sphinx search problem

Tags: mysql, sphinx

group by and count doesn't work in sphinx search v 2.0.1B, why?

```
mysql> select count(*) from my_index group by myattr;
ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected FROM, expecting IDENT near 'from my_index group by myattr'
```

just group by without the count works though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
select count(*) as cnt from my_index group by myattr;
```